# How to type hint a list with different types in specific positions

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to type hint a list that contains multiple types in a specific order. Something like:

```
l: list[str, int] = ["text", 10]
```

Where the first element will always be a `str` and the second always an `int`.
MyPy doesn't accept this as list takes exactly 1 argument. If this were a tuple it would work perfectly well, but I need this to be mutable. If there is a data structure other than a list that would work I'd be open to that. I could probably make a custom class that would behave the way I want, but that seems excessive.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There is no mutable heterogeneous collection in Python, you'll have to create a custom class using either `@dataclass` (recommended) or with an explicit `__init__`.

Comment: Hi, why not `list[Union[str, int]]`?

Comment: Then when I got one of the elements Mypy wouldn't know if it was a string or an int and would complain whenever I did something like `data[0].split()`. This might be solvable with casting, but I don't really want a million casts throughout my program to solve this one problem.